# When can you change order of summations in matrix norms?

Tags: matrices, summation

When can you change the order of summations in matrix norms?

It seems that e.g. for the euclidean norm of $A$, $m \times n$, it's easy to see that

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m a_{i,j}^2\right)^{1/2}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n  a_{i,j}^2\right)^{1/2}$$ since the order of summing individual terms does not change the sum.

But is this how general property?

Does this e.g. apply to norms of multiplied matrices as well?

E.g.

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^p \sum_{i=1}^m a_{i,k}b_{k,j}\right)^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: how exactly do you want to change the order?

Comment: @user251257 Well I'm thinking whether I can change the summations in any order, just like in the two sum case.

Comment: you may obviously switch the $i$ indexed sum with the $j$ indexed sum ... but not with the $k$ indexed sum.

Comment: What if I use C-S inequality to get $$\sum_{k=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^p a_{i,k}^2) (\sum_{i=1}^m b_{k,j}^2)$$. Surely in this I can switch $n$-sum and $p$-sum or $n$-sum and $m$-sum. Just using C-S in order to get yet another example of summation.

Comment: it is an **in**equality, not an equation...